# Formation de "paratraphosphore"

Tags: néologismes

Bonjour,

Dans *Féerie pour une autre fois* II, le narrateur est en train de décrire les bombardements sur Montmartre :

> Ah, les foutres d'avions oiseaux chiures ! **paratraphosphore** !
> l'horreur que ça crache !

Savez-vous quel est l'autre mot utilisé ici par Céline dans la formation de ce néologisme, en plus de *phosphore* ?

Comment: Avoir plus de contexte aiderait à deviner le sens de ce mot. Sinon peut-être le mot (oublié) paratre, équivalent masculin de marâtre.

Comment: Vu le contexte (les bombes, les avions, tout qui vole...) je verrais bien dans cette création lexicale de Céline un amalgame de 
parachute/stratosphère/ et un peu de phosphore pour le plaisir de l'onomatopée. Avec les taratavions qui suivent mélangeant le bruit des tirs (ra-ta-ta-ta) et des avions. Question d'opinion à mon avis. Céline n'est plus là pour qu'on lui pose la question.

Comment: On peut aussi imaginer que l'onomatopée "patatras" ait inspiré cette création, mélangée avec "para".

Comment: @Greg oui tout à fait.

Answer (score 1):

On pourrait voir dans cette phrase une orgie d'images en partie scatologique, que le mot inventé « paratraphosphore » confirme.

> ([wikipedia, paratrooper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paratrooper) A paratrooper is a military parachutist

> ([TLFi, -phore](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-phore)) Élém. tiré du gr. -φ ο ρ ο ς «qui porte, qui transporte» (lui-même tiré de φ ε ́ ρ ε ι ν «porter, transporter»), servant à constr. des subst. masc. du vocab. sc.; le 1er élém., tiré du gr., désigne ce qui est porté, transporté.

> ([TLFi, Doryphore](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/doryphore))
>
> A.− HIST. ANTIQUE. Soldat armé d'une lance, appartenant à certaines milices ou servant de garde du corps.
>
> B.− ENTOMOL. et usuel. **Coléoptère** s'attaquant aux feuilles de différentes plantes et en partic. coléoptère originaire d'Amérique, qui se nourrit des feuilles de pommes de terre. Synon. bête à patate, mouche à patate.
> **Rem.** D'apr. Privat-Foc. 1870 ,,Leur poitrine est armée d'une longue pointe dirigée en avant qui leur a valu leur nom`` (explication valable uniquement pour les espèces autres que le doryphore s'attaquant aux feuilles de pommes de terre).
> − P. anal., pop. ou fam. et péj. (gén. au plur.).
> **Militaires allemands** ainsi appelés par la population française des zones occupées pendant la guerre de 1939-1945 en raison de leur nombre

> [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doryphore#%C3%89tymologie) « Doryphore », d'après le nom générique Doryphora, vient du grec « δορυφόρος », porte-lance (δόρυ, lance et φόρος, qui porte), et ne semble pas avoir de rapport direct avec l'insecte. Ce nom aurait été donné à d'autres espèces apparentées, dont l'adulte est porteur d’une pièce thoracique avec une longue pointe dirigée en avant.

> ([Wikipédia, phosphore](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphore) Le nom dérive du mot grec φώσφορος (phosphoros), qui signifie « porteur de lumière » et évoque la planète Vénus, l'étoile du berger. Cette origine a été attribuée au fait que le phosphore blanc émet de la lumière visible dans l'obscurité quand il est exposé à l'air, par chimiluminescence.

- Ah, les foutres d'avions oiseaux chiures ! paratraphosphore ! l'horreur que ça crache !

[image]

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4a/U.S._Army%2C_British_and_Italian_paratroopers_Pordenone%2C_Italy_191203-A-JM436-0590C.jpg

*Les « chiures de mouches » de Céline*

« Avions oiseaux chiures » rime avec « oiseau mouche » et « chiures de mouche » (très courant pour « excréments de mouche », cependant, mouche ou doryphore, qu'importe, encore un insecte, et on confond les deux pour voir maintenant aussi un soldat grec porteur de lance et péjorativement l'envahisseur allemand bien connu comme mangeur de pommes de terres (l'insecte mange seulement les feuilles), d'où s'ensuit un doryphore porte-lance en l'avion allemand porte-parachutiste, lui-même l'envahisseur en personne, d'où les grappes de parachutistes qui sont ses excréments, mais qui restent tout de même, en plus d'être des amas d'excrément, des amas de points lumineux dans le ciel, ce que le phosphore évoque (les parachutes étaient blancs pendant la seconde guerre mondiale).